# How to compare list using contains() for initial substrings with Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, substring

I have some list values I want to check against another list of conditions.

For example, the condition list I want to check against is `['042', '043', '044']`. I want to return True as long as the initial substring contains any of these values.

For example, `['04233']`, `['042']` or `['042', '011']` should return True. But for `['11042']` or `['13044']`, even though it contains the check conditions as substring, because they are not the initial characters, they should return `False`.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['152042']) #'04211'
df.columns=['test_list']

cond_list = ['042', '043', '044']

print (df['test_list'].str.contains('|'.join(cond_list)).any())

# Return True, but False is desired.
```

I am not sure how I can incorporating both substring checking and at the same time ensuring the subtrings occur as leading characters.

Comment: Use `^` to assert a match at the start of a string

Comment: change contains to startswith

Comment: @user3483203 let me write it to an answer .

Comment: http://xion.io/post/code/python-startswith-tuple.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the general idea, you just need to add an assertion to match at the beginning of your string, using a `^` character.

```
rgx = '^({})'.format('|'.join(cond_list))
# '^(042|043|044)'

df['test_list'].str.contains(rgx).any()
```

```
False
```

Comment: I got a warning "UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  1 if row[var_name_list].str.contains(rgx).any() else 0, axis=1)", is this not a concern?

Comment: Not a concern, if the warning bothers you, you can convert the matching group to be non-capturing: `rgx = '^(?:{})'.format('|'.join(cond_list))`

Answer (score 3):

Using `startswith`, notice it accpet `tuple` not `list`

```
df['test_list'].str.startswith(tuple(cond_list))
Out[47]: 
0    False
Name: test_list, dtype: bool
```